# How do I record my repo's subtree settings?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I created a subtree in my main repo by following the instructions here: [How to move a subdirectory into a separate Git repository](https://www.deployhq.com/git/faqs/detatch-subdirectory-git-submodule).

However I don't see any step that records this setting into my main repo. After I push a commit and clone a clean copy from Github, the new one doesn't know anything about the subtree I set up.

How do I get the main repo to remember my subtree setup, so that I can push and clone it (e.g. to another machine)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a subtree you created. According with article's name you created **separate** repo inside your main repo with usage of `git subtree split` command. For creating subtree repo you have to use `git subtree add` command after point "Preparing the current repository". You could see [this](https://%20https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree). After adding subtree and pushing changes to remoute main repo, your main project will know about this subtree. And if you will clone it, subtree folder will be inside.